# Can a window of excel (for example "custom sort" window) appear by macro?

Tags: excel, vba

I do not want to sort a range by VBA because the sort window is more general and give more selection. The sort window in excel can  appear by the shortcut: "Alt + H + S + U". But can we write a macro that (select a special range of a sheet and)  show this window?

Comment: The question is unclear. Anything you can do in the UI can be done with a macro though. You can even record your UI actions as a macro to find out what code is needed to do what you want

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos By record a macro we can not do this because when we show the custom sort window, then we should stop the recorder, but this is impossible(because the sort window in active and stop recorder in not active)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the activecell is filterable then use:

> ```
> Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSort).Show
> ```